# Building .exe via shell causes extra character in file name

Tags: bash, gcc, compilation, cygwin, sh

I'm trying to create a shell script via cygwin that will automatically build an executable and run it.  It's a very simple format of

```
#!/bin/bash
gcc test.c -o hello
./hello.exe
```

When I enter the 2nd and 3rd lines separately, everything works normally.  However, if I save those 3 lines into a .sh file, the resulting .exe built has some extra character added in that will always throw off the last line.

```
hello.exe
```

I can't even replicate the file name because no tool, including the character map/MS word/other ASCII tools online will give me any result.  Some online tool gave me the ASCII result &#61453, but as far as I can tell that doesn't correspond to anything meaningful.  How can I avoid this problem in my shell script?

Answer (score 2):

Very likely you have Windows linefeeds in the .sh file. Make sure you have Unix linefeeds.

Comment: What's the simplest way I can indicate a Unix linefeed rather than a Windows linefeed?  Can't seem to find a very simple solution

Comment: Depends on your tools. I'd use the dos2unix command line utility. A good editor would let you configure this.